# How to disable alternative international keyboard

Tags: gnome, keyboard, internationalization

During installation I selected the alternative international keyboard. The problem with this keyboard that a double-quote character doesn't get typed until a space is pressed. Same for tilde (~) and single quote (').

I cannot get this keyboard removed. I tried to click on my keyboard applet, selecting keyboard preferences, removing the alternative keyboard. But every time I restart, the alternative keyboard is back again.

How can this be removed?

Comment: Have you tried adding another one (US non-international) and *then* removing the international one? Unfortunately keyboards layouts have long been plagued by bugs.

Comment: @loevborg: Yes, I tried. It's really frustrating that it keeps getting back to the alternative keyboard, if if you try to remove it.

Comment: I would encourage you to file a bug on launchpad.

Comment: @loevborg: Thanks, I wasn't sure it was a bug: I filled a bug for it now: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ubiquity/+bug/782941

Comment: I didn't yet get any reaction on my filed bug. I hope that others on askubuntu have some fixes for me.

Comment: Have you tried clicking 'Apply System-wide'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

install the other keyboard setting and select the proper keyboard setting when logging in.

Comment: Thanks! The answer looks quite trivial, but if you do not know it, it's really frustrating that changing the keyboard settings doesn't give you a warning that you cannot remove the selected keyboard setting.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot remove a keyboard layout if it's set as default for the session. Log out, change the layout for the session from the menu at the bottom panel, log in again, then you can remove it in the keyboard preferences.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I'll accept @dago's answer because he was a bit earlier than you, although your's is more verbose.

Answer (score 0):

You can type

> sudo dpkg-reconfigure console-setup

in order to reconfigure the console and X default keyboard settings.

The default layout is stored in `/etc/default/console-setup` and the above script edits the configuration file.

Comment: It doesn't help: my bug is relatied to the X environment, not the console environment.